# WSO2 MB - How to Get Publisher IP or ID

Tags: jms, wso2, messagebroker, publisher, subscriber

in a use case in which i have N publishers on a topic and M subscribers to the same topic, when a message is delivered, is there the native possibility for a each subscriber to know which was the actual publisher (by an ID or an IP field)? Is this information stored into the header of the message (i.e. setting the JMSReplyTo header)? or have i to set it manually adding some custom property?
thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom jms header like  textMessage.setStringProperty("ip", "127.0.0.1");

read it using message.getStringProperty("ip");